# Is that correct way to use .bind function in this situation?

Tags: javascript, oop, reference, bind, assign

I would like to know your opinion which is the best way to do that:

I have two classes:

```typescript
class Application {
    ...
    pause() {}
    resume() {}
    ...
}
```

(Just image that the `Application` class is a big one. Which has a lot of methods and properties.)

```typescript
class System {
    constructor(app: Application) {
        this.pauseCallback = app.pause.bind(app)
        this.resumeCallback = app.resume.bind(app)
    }
    
    onWindowInactive() {
        this.pauseCallback()
    }

    onWindowActive() {
        this.resumeCallback()
    }
}
```

The reason why I'm using `.bind` function on these methods is because I don't want to assign a reference to `Application` class in `System` class. So, I can do like `this.app.pause()` but I don't want to do that.

Instead of this I'm creating new functions using `.bind` and assigning them to `System` class properties. Then I can use `pause` and `resume` methods of `Application`

Is that the correct way to do that and what about performance and memory allocation?

Comment: Yes, it's fine and works, but I'd name them `pauseApplication` and `resumeApplication` (instead of `…Callback`).

Comment: "*I can do like `this.app.pause()` but I don't want to do that.*" - why not? You really should. It's even shorter. (And a tiny bit more memory-efficient, but that's insignificant, especially since it looks like you have only a single instance of these classes anyway)

Comment: Thank you @Bergi! I really appreciate your answer. But what about if I have other (15 instances for example) which have a reference to ```System``` class. I have a ```Scene``` class which has a reference to ```System``` class and I have 15 instances of it (15 scenes). If the ```System``` class has a reference to ```Application``` class it would be a lot of memory I think. What do you think?

Comment: Does each scene have its own system or do they all reference the same system? No, they don't have references to the `System` class, they have references to *instances* of `System`. And no, 15 is not a lot.

Comment: They all reference to the same instance of ```System```. I have only one instance of ```System``` class.

Comment: So you have only one instance in memory, as I guessed.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Еverything is clear! Thank you @Bergi! I really appreciate it!